# Connect to SockJS from Java?

Tags: java, sockjs

I've written a basic servern with SockJS in nodejs. I cant connect from a browser by using the JavaScript lib and everything works just fine.

However now i want to connect a client that I've written in Java. Is there any lib or example to show how to accomplish this?

I have tried: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

But cant get it to connect

Comment: could you share your solution if you found appropriate one ?

Comment: out of interest did you find any example of a java client?  I am having similar problems

Comment: Can you post code showing what you've tried?

Answer (score -1):

Here the example, based on Spring Framework 4.0: 
https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio